# Rails - Can't make the right queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models

In my app, a `Person` can have a `Group`, and a Group can be owned by just one person. But persons can be part of groups too, not as owners, but as members. A Group can have more than one member. So to a person become a member, she/he needs to ask for `Group_Membership`. This way, a group_membership model is created, with a `boolean status` with `false` as default. The Group owner than let the member in by changing the `status` to `true`.  Here are the models:

```
class Person
has_many :groups
has_many :group_memberships, :foreign_key => "member_id"
end

class Group_Membership
belongs_to :member, :class_name => 'Person'
belongs_to :group
scope :asked, where(:status => false)
end

class Group
belongs_to :person
has_many :group_memberships
has_many :members, :class_name => "Person", :through => "group_memberships", :foreign_key => "member_id"
```

What I need is to display in the `person#show` the groups that the person is in, and as well the requests that the person got to the groups owned by him/her.

```
def show
@person = Person.find(params[:id])
@asked_membership = @person.group_memberships.asked.where(:member_id => params[:id]) 
@group = @person.groups.where(:person_id => params[:id])
@asked_group = @person.group_memberships.asked.where(:group_id => params[@group])
end
```

With that I'm able to see the groups that a person is in, even though I set my `status` in `scope` as false to test (since status is false by default should show all the requests made by the person). This is the view:

```
    <% @asked_membership.each do |group_membership| %>
    <%=h group_membership.member_id %>
```

How can I can display using this view the name of the groups instead of `member_id`?

And `@asked_group` is the right query for me to get the all the requests that were made from other persons to join the group owned by the person in question? If so, `(:group_id => params[@group])` is always getting null value and I don't know how to repair it.

Thanks in advance.

**##EDIT##**

Changing `@asked_group` to `@asked_group = @person.group_memberships.asked.where(:group_id => @group.id)` and adding this to the `Group Controller` made it work. Now, still need to display name of the groups instead of `member_id`.

Comment: You should have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `Person` and `Group`, because each can have many of the other. This relationship involves building the intermediate table `GroupPerson`, which you can add any fields to you want when you create it using a migration.

Comment: Even if a Group can be owned just for one person? Taken from rails guides, *You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks, or extra attributes on the join model*, and I have `status` in the join model.

Comment: if you set up a relationship that allows for multiple, it can deal with a single. See, this way, one person can own one or more groups, and one group can 'own' one or more people. I haven't checked, but you might be able to do a two-way `has_many, :through` and specify `GroupMembership` as your `:through` model.

Comment: Just a note: indenting your code makes it easier to read not only for other people but also for yourself. Please try to do this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite your models as follows:

```
class Person
  has_many :owned_groups, :class_name => "Group", :foreign_key => :owner_id
  has_many :owned_group_memberships, :through => :owned_groups, 
              :source => :group_memberships 

  has_many :group_memberships, :foreign_key => "member_id"
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_memberships

  has_many :approved_groups, :through => :group_memberships, :source => :group, 
               :conditions => [ "group_memberships.status = ? ", true]

  has_many :applied_groups, :through => :group_memberships,, :source => :group, 
               :conditions => [ "group_memberships.status = ? ", false]

end

class GroupMembership
  belongs_to :member, :class_name => 'Person'
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "Person"
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :members, :through => :group_memberships

  has_many :approved_members,:through => :group_memberships, :source => :member, 
               :conditions => [ "group_memberships.status = ? ", true]

  has_many :applied_members,:through => :group_memberships, :source => :member, 
               :conditions => [ "group_memberships.status = ? ", false]

end
```

Now given a `person`:

```
# returns all the groups is user is member of
person.groups

# returns all the groups owned by the user                  
person.owned_groups                

# returns the memberships of all the groups owned by the user
person.owned_group_memberships 

# returns the memberships requests for all the groups owned by the user
person.owned_group_memberships.find_all_by_status(false)
```

You can further optimize the results by eager loading the group and member:

```
@asked_group_memberships=person.owned_group_memberships.find_all_by_status(false,
  :include => [:group, :member])
```

In your view:

```
<% @asked_group_memberships.each do | agm| %>
  <p> 
      Requester: <%= agm.member.name %>, 
      Group: <%=agm.group.name%> 
  </p>
<%end %>
```

To check if a person is a member of a group:

```
person.groups.exists?(group)
```

To check if a person is a member of a approved group:

```
person.approved_groups.exists?(group)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put on the answer! Can you explain me why `has_many :owned_group_memberships` must go `:through => :owned_groups`?

Comment: I removed the `:through => "group_memberships"` from `has_many :groups`, was giving me an error...

Comment: How can I return the groups a person is member, but don't own?

Comment: Answer to your original comment: The owner ship link is established through `owner_id` column, i.e. `owned_groups`.

Comment: Answer to your 2nd comment: I have fixed the code. Try again.

Comment: If I make `person.groups` to get all the memberships a person has (the groups he/she is in but isnt owner), gives me this `Could not find the association "group_memberships" in model Profile`

Comment: This can happen if you haven't added `has_many :group_memberships, :foreign_key => "member_id"` to `Person` model. PS:Is the model `Profile` = model `Person`.

Comment: Do you know how can I make a query so I block a person to ask 2 times or more for a `group_membership?`. Have been trying to get it by `group.members` but says the association can't be found in the model. `<% unless @group.person == current_person || @group.person.id == @group.members.member_id%> <%= submit_tag "Join Group!" %>`

Comment: Updated my answer take a look.

Comment: Perfect as always :)
If you want, I opened a new question for this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090632/rails-model-doubt
Make an answer there with the link or something like that so I can accept yours.